# Есть ли в Unity 2D прямоугольный свет?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

я недавно начал изучать 2D свет в Unity и у меня появился вопрос: Есть ли прямоугольный свет(именно прямоугольная область, которая светится)? И как её активировать?
Прошу объяснить подробнее, так как я не знаю куда тут тыкать.

Answer (score 1):

Если зайти в документацию к юнити в раздел освещения и просто промотать вниз, можно увидеть

Area lights
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lighting.html

И это именно то что ты просишь.
Не знаешь куда тыкать - в первую очередь забиваешь в гугл на английском языке. Меня на стриницу документации буквально привел запрос "Rectangle Light" из заголовка твоего вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]